# Javascript: Improve code having nested foreach loops

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

Just wondering if the two forEach loops can be flattened or can be replaced with any any other more efficient solution. My GOOGLE_CRITERIA list is too long (~1000 elements) and nested forEach loops are being an overkill.

```
const openAddressSearch = ({ addressResponse, customerName }) => {
    addressResponse.forEach(address => {
        GOOGLE_CRITERIA.forEach(googleCriteria => {
            if (address.get('addressLine1')) {
                let addressCriteria = address
                    .filter((value, name) => name.startsWith('addressLine') && value)
                    .map(addressLine => `"${addressLine}"`)
                    .join('+');
                addressCriteria += googleCriteria;
                window.open(
                    buildGoogleSearchUrl({
                        customerName,
                        criteria: addressCriteria,
                    }),
                    '_blank',
                );
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: You could build that `addressCriteria` outside the inner `.forEach()`, since the address won't change. Also, that `.map()` looks totally unnecessary to me.

Comment: if you want to speed up this loop, try changing to a [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop instead of the `.forEach()`. You could also move the `addressCriteria` outside of the inner loop since it is not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for?

```
const openAddressSearch = ({ addressResponse, customerName }) => {
    addressResponse.forEach(address => {
        if (address.get('addressLine1')) {
            let addressCriteria = address
                .filter((value, name) => name.startsWith('addressLine') && value)
                .map(addressLine => `"${addressLine}"`)
                .join('+');
            GOOGLE_CRITERIA.forEach(googleCriteria => {
                window.open(
                    buildGoogleSearchUrl({
                        customerName,
                        criteria: (addressCriteria + googleCriteria),
                    }),
                    '_blank',
                );
            });
        }
    });
};
```